# JScrollPane set enabled to false

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I've JScrollPane with table inside it.

```
scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
scroll.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
add(scroll);
```

I want to disable it, but

```
scroll.setEnabled(false);
```

does nothing.

Is there a way to disable scroll pane?

Comment: do you want to disable scrolling or whole component?

Comment: I want to disable whole component I know I can disable scrolling with scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setEnabled(false);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JScrollPane.setEnabled(false)` does not work as suggested, [it is a bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4286743), in order to get the same behavior you need to do the following:

```
scroll.getHorizontalScrollBar().setEnabled(false);
scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setEnabled(false);
scroll.getViewport().getView().setEnabled(false);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is a trackpad gesture (multi-touch swipe) that makes the view of the table change, even if the view is disabled.